# Adding heading tags around a shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I have a shortcode [tab title] which currently is used to display tab titles above tabbed content, see here: http://flatsome.uxthemes.com/shortcodes/shortcode-tabs-accordian/

I'm looking to add h2 tags around these tab titles for seo reasons, but I'm not sure where to start with the php code to do that, anybody able to help? Thanks

Comment: I've never used that plugin, but if you are very lucky you might be able to add the tags directly in the shortcode directly in the page, e.g. `[tabgroup title="<h2>title</h2>"]`. But if that doesn't work, I'd strongly suggest finding a way to tell your boss to wait until your developer is free - changing plugin functionality is a big ask of someone with no development experience, and one tiny mistake could break the page, or even "white screen" the entire website. And we're talking something as small as a misplaced bracket! Do you really want to be responsible for bringing the whole site down?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very vague, try being more specific with your question.

However, if you literally mean you haven't coded before, then it's not PHP you're looking for in this exact example, it's just plain old HTML.

Simply put:

```
<h2> Tab Title </h2>
```

Around whatever you want to make a header. If you're asking to make the Tab Title's dynamic also, then:

```
$query = "SELECT tab_title FROM whereveryoustoreyourtabtitles ORDER BY 
tab_id DESC"
$get_tab_title_query = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_tab_title_query)){
$tab_title = $row['tab_title'];
echo "<h2>$tab_title</h2>;
}
```

If you know the tab titles, and want to automatically ensure they are placed with header tags as described, you can do this:

```
$tab_titles = array("Tabtitle1", "Tabtitle2", "Tabtitle3");
echo "[tabgroup title='Tab Group']";

foreach($tab_titles as $title){
echo "[tab title='$title']<h2> $title </h2> [/tab]";
}
echo "[/tabgroup]";
```

Remember that as you said you've never code before, PHP code must be surrounded by the tags

Comment: hi, sorry maybe I wasn't specific enough - I'm looking to change ALL tab titles to include h2 tags, so when a new tab is created it will automatically have the h2 tags on output. Is this what the second piece of code you've created do? Sorry yes, i haven't used php before! Thanks

Comment: @Craig That's okay. So that second piece of code is an example to fetch code from a database. I'll update the answer to show what to do if the values are static (AKA You know the tab titles and don't want to change them dynamically)

Comment: @Craig I've made the edits, if you're happy with it, accept and upvote please.

Comment: Hey, cheers for the reply - so I don't know the tab titles as they'll only be created in the future, so i guess it isn't the second answer? If it's the first one, ie apply to all new tabs and existing tabs whatever the title may be, what would i put in place of 'FROM whereveryoustoreyourtabtitles ORDER BY'

Comment: @Craig I'd be very hesitant of making such drastic changes when they are not necessary. If you change the base code of your plugin, that means you can't upgrade it anymore, without having to redo the change every time. You say you are doing this for SEO, so if that's the only reason I wouldn't bother - Google is clever enough to expect markup to be what should occur naturally on a page. Id they decide that you are trying to over-optimise the page, then they could actually penalise you and you could actually do more harm than good.

Comment: @Craig so the problem is bud if you've never used PHP or MySQL or HTML, I'm unsure why you've been put in charge of this. You need to read up on PHP and mySQL databases. Essentially you have to have a database on a server, connect to that database via PHP, and then submit content and retreive content from your database(s) via PHP. It's quite a task.

Comment: Yeah the client (seo agency) has asked for it - I'm a graphic designer and our developer isn't free. It's been done on something else so not a major job to do, i just can't find the code in the functions file to copy it and apply to tabs that's all

Comment: @Craig cmprogram's right - it's not an easy task, especially if you have no development experience. Changing the functionality of an existing plugin can be a daunting task even for people with moderate experience.

Comment: I appreciate the heads up guys, but it's not a plugin it's part of the theme so I was just looking to add into functions.php. As i mentioned, it's been done already on the site for accordion titles so i was just looking to extend this to include tab titles. I'll wait for our developer to take a look. Cheers for the help

Comment: @Craig Theme/plugin... its all the same in this case. A plugin just pulls functionality out of the theme so it can be reused - it still requires the same amount of work and it still makes the theme or plugin non-upgradable.

Comment: We're using a child theme so the functions file is fine if the theme updates, that's my understanding?